# How can I make myself eligible for Mechatronic Engg. faculty with PhD in Electrical engg,?

Tags: faculty-application

My major in PhD is Telecommunication and there is one position for Mechatronic Engineer. How can I make myself eligible for the post. Since I am electronic engineering graduate with masters in Aerospace engineering, I have sufficient skills to take Mechatronic engineering as a faculty.

However, my last degree (PhD) is in Telecommunication. Any suggestions about what should I put in my application which can weigh in as something special?

Answer (score 2):

**You're applying for a job. Treat it like any other job application.** Write a cover letter introducing yourself, explaining where you heard about your job, and how you meet the posted job criteria, and attach it to a copy of your CV, which should include all relevant details of your previous work and study experience (and, depending on region, might also be expected to include a comprehensive list of all previous employment and study).